# Weird behaviour when loading images in NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview, nstablecellview

I'm loading images with GCD, I got some strange behaviour.

When you scroll though the table view, every album starts fetching the artwork.
The `NSTableCellView` quickly displays many wrong artworks, until after maybe a second it finally displays the correct one and then stops.

Obviously this means, after the dispatching the variable of the `NSTableCellView` doesn't point to the same instance anymore, which causes to change the image of the same cell over and over again.

I tried to fix this by calling `viewAtColumn:row:indexOfObject:` in the dispatching block, but it does not fix the problem.

Any suggestions?

---

### Code

```
- (ITAlbumTableCellView *)makeTableCellViewWithAlbum:(ITLibAlbum *)album {
    ITAlbumTableCellView *cellView = (ITAlbumTableCellView *)[self makeTableCellViewWithIdentifier:kTCVIAlbum];

    // ... Mapping Stuff

    // Set artwork
    if (![self._imageCache objectForKey:album]) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            NSImage *artwork = album.artwork;
            if (!artwork || !artwork.isValid) artwork = [NSImage imageNamed:@"noArtwork"];

            [self._imageCache setObject:artwork forKey:album];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSTableCellView *tcv = [self.tableView viewAtColumn:0 row:[self.tableContent indexOfObject:album] makeIfNecessary:NO];
                tcv.imageView.image = artwork;
            });
        });
    } else {
        cellView.imageView.image = [self._imageCache objectForKey:album];
    }

    return cellView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use reusable cells, so when cell hide outside the bounds, it's reuse for display another data. Quick fix:

```
 - (ITAlbumTableCellView *)makeTableCellViewWithAlbum:(ITLibAlbum *)album {
ITAlbumTableCellView *cellView = (ITAlbumTableCellView *)[self makeTableCellViewWithIdentifier:kTCVIAlbum];
static int tag = 0;
tag++;
int tagForBlock = tag;
cellView.tag = tag;
if (![self._imageCache objectForKey:album]) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSImage *artwork = album.artwork;
        if (!artwork || !artwork.isValid) artwork = [NSImage imageNamed:@"noArtwork"];

        [self._imageCache setObject:artwork forKey:album];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if(tagForBlock != cellView.tag)
                return;
            NSTableCellView *tcv = [self.tableView viewAtColumn:0 row:[self.tableContent indexOfObject:album] makeIfNecessary:NO];
            tcv.imageView.image = artwork;
        });
    });
} else {
    cellView.imageView.image = [self._imageCache objectForKey:album];
}

return cellView;
}
```

Comment: There is no `setTag:` method, the property is readonly. What should I use instead

Comment: How?) What kind of class ITAlbumTableCellView? UITableViewCell? You really simple need to determine what data present in cell.

Comment: Never mind, I added a new property to a `NSTableCellView` subclass, it's working now, thanks!

Comment: No it's `NSTableCellView`

Comment: Read the title, I wrote NSTableView, as well as only added the **OSX** tag